# Vuetify button color and Icon not working

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

**Vuetify button color, other color and Icons not working**

I already installed laravel, vue2 , vuetify2 and inertia js on my project. I copy some of UI Component code from vuetifyjs.com and paste to my project. Everything work fine but color and icons don't work.

*package.json*

```
 "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.1.1",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "~1.32",
        "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
        "vuex": "3.1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.10.1",
        "@inertiajs/inertia-vue": "^0.7.2",
        "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.6",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-dropdowns": "^20.2.43",
        "laravel-vue-pagination": "^2.3.1",
        "numeral": "^2.0.6",
        "print-js": "^1.6.0",
        "vue-carousel-3d": "^1.0.1",
        "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
        "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
        "vue-toastr": "^2.1.2",
        "vue2-datepicker": "^3.11.0",
        "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.7",
        "vuetify": "^2.6.3",
        "ziggy-js": "^1.4.3"
    }
```

*webpack.min.js*

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

*vuetify.js*

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
    icons:{
        iconfont:'mdi' || 'fa',
    },
    theme: {
        themes: {
            dark: {
                background: '#EEEEEE'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

*my codes*

```
     <v-btn
       class="mx-2"
       fab
       dark
       large
       color="purple"
    >
       <v-icon dark>
         mdi-android
       </v-icon>
    </v-btn>
```

[this is my output button on my project with no color and no icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGp7x.png)

[my expected output was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6X1u.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the highest level template wraps all your content in `<v-app></v-app>` as this special component has predefined css classes associated with it that is key to styling working correctly.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/

> In order for your application to work properly, you must wrap it in a v-app component. This component is required for ensuring proper cross-browser compatibility. Vuetify doesn’t support multiple isolated Vuetify instances on a page. v-app can exist anywhere inside the body of your app, however, there should only be one and it must be the parent of ALL Vuetify components.

## Getting the icons working

Vuetify 2 does not support multiple icon libraries.

`iconfont:'mdi' || 'fa'` would always evaluate to `mdi` because you are basically doing an operation `true or true`, the first true value would return since a `string` is treated as value that always quates to `true`.

```js
const value = 'mdi' || 'fa'

document.querySelector("#font-preference").innerHTML = value
```

```html
My font preference will always be: <strong id="font-preference"></strong>
```

To get the MDI icons to work, you should replace

`import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'`

with

`import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'`

And you should have added the npm/yarn package `@mdi/font` for offline usage.

See here for the above setup or alternatively to just use the CDN method:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#material-design-icons

Comment: Yes thanks sir. I already added v-app on main panel layout file and also added <slot></slot>. This file had imported from all file like  <main-panel>   my code here ...</main-panel>. Now color work but Icon still don't work.

Comment: I have updated my answer on getting the icons to work.

Comment: All work well coz of you. Thank you so much sir!